# How many points does it require to create a badge for a tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, badges

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags), "If enough upvotes are earned in a tag – any tag – the badge will be automatically created and awarded."

How many points/votes does a particular tag require before it will garner its own badge?  It appears that the answer is "400 upvotes" judging by the other tags listed on that page, but I wanted to see if there was a less speculative answer.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, 400 votes (not points) for silver; 1000 for gold (only counted for votes on non-community-wiki answers).

See the blog: [Specialist Badge Implemented](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/specialist-badge-implemented/)